# Local Rings, How to prove Z/(P^l)Z is a local ring

Tags: elementary-number-theory

please do me a great favor to answer my following question:

Is the ring Z/(P^l)Z a local ring? If it 's the case what is its maximal principal ideal ?

Comment: I m studying p-adic gauss sums and when reading a paper about them I found that those kind of sums are defining in local rings and give the example of Z/(P^l)Z .I looked for the definition of such rings i.e local rings and I found that are rings which posses one maximal ideal ring that is why  I m asking what is the unique maximal ring of Z/(P^l)Z

Comment: You might want to do some reviewing of basic ring theory before looking further into $p$-adic Gauss sums. This particular case is fairly straightforward and a basic exercise.

Comment: Please to gain a time can you indicate me some practical references

Comment: The thing is, that local rings are usually only introduced fairly late in most cases, since most interesting results about them require a bit extra background. So once one gets to the definition, I would usually expect an exercise like this to be fairly trivial, and I am not aware of some text that covers the basics and introduces local rings so early. But to review the basics, take pretty much any textbook on abstract algebra.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}$ are in bijection with maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $p^i\mathbb{Z}$.

But now, a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by a prime, and this contains $p^i\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if...

Comment: Thank you very much Crostul

Comment: Can I deduce that we the Z/(P^l)Z posses just one maximal ideal throug this bijection and that there is no a cocrete expression of it?

Comment: @moksih Oh, come on! The only maximal ideal is obviously $pZ/p^iZ$

Comment: Thank you very much. Excuse me for being too so slowly to deduce evident things.

Comment: Just a last favor, can you indicate me any references where appears the above bijection

Comment: @moksih http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Second_isomorphism_theorem_2

Comment: Thank you very very ...much.